# How to modify instance variable from separate AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

let's say i have an activity with instance variable **loadedMovie** and a method that executes **AsyncTask** which is in another file

```
class MainActivity:AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

 var loadedMovie: Movie? = null

 ....

 fun loadMovie() {
   val task = LoadMovieTask(this)

   task.execute()
 }
}
```

separate **AsyncTask**

```
class LoadMovieTask(val ctx: Activity) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

  var movie: Movie? = null

  override fun onPreExecute() {
    ....
  }

  // loading information from network
  override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {
    movie = load()

    return null
  }

  // here i modify views with help of kotlin android extensions
  override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
    ....
  }
}
```

problem is: somehow i can't modify ***loadedMovie*** neither from **doInBackground** (which is ok, because it runs on separate thread) and **onPostExecute** (which is not ok)

i just type *ctx.loadedMovie* in **onPostExecute** and it's not there.. maybe i don't understand something? or maybe there is another way to do it that i'm not aware of

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a

Comment: You should use weak reference to hold the activity in async task or else memory leak might happen.

Comment: how to make it weakreference ?

Comment: weak references are well documented for the JVM and Java and all of that documentation applies to Kotlin.  This isn't your main problem though as asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
class LoadMovieTask(val ctx: MainActivity)
```

instead of

```
class LoadMovieTask(val ctx: Activity)
```

MainActivity has the method and not the Android's Activity class itself. So even though you need the context, since you are trying to access the method specific to MainActivity, it is required to pass that

Comment: It would help the author and future readers of the question if you were to explain why this change is needed.

Comment: @JaysonMinard Thanks for the input, have modified the answer with the reason